# How to store 13-bit structure?

Tags: c#, mpeg2-ts

I want to create a class that represents an [MPEG 2 Transport Stream packet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream). I want to have a class property that stores the 13 bit PID value? What would be the best data type? Would you use a mask to store this value? I'm thinking I should just convert the value to an int...that would be easiest solution right? How do you store different numbers of bits that are not a byte?

```
public class Mpeg2TransportPacket
{
    byte SyncByte { get; set; }
    bool TransportErrorIndicator { get; set; }
    bool PayloadUnitStartIndicator { get; set; }
    bool TransportPriority { get; set; }

    int PID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: A `byte` is 8-bits, a `short` (`Int16`) is 16-bits.  You can use a `short`, with 3 spare bits.

Comment: I'd convert it to a `short`.

Comment: Wait until you get to the 33bit pts stored in 6 bytes :)

Comment: @szatmary haha lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a single value like that I would think that System.Int16 would be fine.

If you need to mask out 13 bits you would use a mask and & operation

```
var mask = 0b0001_1111_1111_1111; // c# v7.0 binary literal, low order bits
var pid = value & mask; // value is what you are applying the mask to
```

Answer (score 0):

I would store the PID into a [BitArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray(v=vs.110).aspx) class and then map each boolean property of your class to write/read from such class

For better performances, use [BitVector32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32(v=vs.110).aspx).